# How do I extract values from a jsonb array of objects?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I am using Postgres and I am trying to get all the elements in the array that's has a keys statusCode and place the values into an array so I can display it.

```
"systemStatuses": [
        {
            "changedBy": "monsjenni557",
            "timeStamp": 1554151540.9612856,
            "statusCode": "S01",
            "statusDescription": "Received"
        },
        {
            "changedBy": "monsjenni557",
            "timeStamp": 1554151546.2600567,
            "statusCode": "SF02",
            "statusDescription": "Request Validation Fail"
        }
    ]
```

the result should be `["S01","SF02"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can expand and then aggregate back the jsonb field. The `WITH` section is only here for example purposes.

```
WITH exampleData AS (
    SELECT '[
        {
            "changedBy": "monsjenni557",
            "timeStamp": 1554151540.9612856,
            "statusCode": "S01",
            "statusDescription": "Received"
        },
        {
            "changedBy": "monsjenni557",
            "timeStamp": 1554151546.2600567,
            "statusCode": "SF02",
            "statusDescription": "Request Validation Fail"
        }
    ]'::jsonb as regionSales
)

SELECT (
    SELECT jsonb_agg( sale -> 'statusCode')
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(regionSales) AS sale
)

FROM exampleData
```

Comment: Can you example where to sale and the exampleData is coming from?

Comment: `exampleData` in the `WITH` section is just here to make a working example. If you copy-paste this as a query it will work as is. I made the assumption that `systemStatuses` is the name of a field in your table, so I guess you would have to replace `exampleData` with your table name, but without more context it is difficult to tell :)